# How to create an alertDialog containing a list of items?

Tags: android, android-dialog

How can I create an `alertDialog` which consists of a list of items defined in the code. I want the alert similar to this:

[image]

I have seen [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) but still I'm not able to create the alert.

Comment: I am not able to create the alert => Why? What happened?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. check the link has code snippets

Comment: add your code so we can see the problem

Comment: what error did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. i think this will definitely  helps you

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setTitle("Pick Colour");
            dialog.setItems(R.array.colors,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"selected Item:"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    }
```

let me know if you have any doubts.